# I can not delete product from OpenCart if use Firefox

Tags: opencart, product

I use OC version 1.5.5.1 and have strange probem. When I check product in catalog-product list in admin panel and click on DELETE in any other browser then Firefox it shows up popup dialog box with standard message - Are you sure you want to delete...etc and two buttons - OK and Cancel and that works fine.

But - in Firefox browser this popup is way too quick it shows and close in metter a second, maby less and I can not click on OK button and can not delete product.

Any advice?